# CSV to XML using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, csv, jaxb, marshalling

**Background**
I have a situation where I can get data either in the form of an XML-file or Excel/CSV-files. In case the data comes in a non-XML format it will be divided into several different files/tables, representing different subsections of the XML. The end goal is to validate the data and generate a valid XML-file using an existing schema, regardless of the format of the indata.

When receiving an XML-file the idea is to unmarshall and validate it. For simple errors autmatic fixes will be applied, and in the end a new XML-file will be marshalled from the JAXB classes.

**Question**
In order to be able to generalize as much as possible of the solution, my idea was to try to generate a JAXB representation of the non-XML data too, and then generate the end XML-file from those classes. I have been trying to find a good tutorial or introduction to converting non-XML to a JAXB representation, but I haven't really been able to find anything useful, which makes me wonder, is this a really bad approach? Any better suggestions for how to solve this problem? In the majority of the cases the files are likely to be non-XML, so I am willing to throw out the current approach if anyone has better solution that uses some other technology.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked before with [univocity parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial). They work well and are simple to use to converting CSV to Java object which then you searialize using JAXB as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will have look.